# Backup iTunes (store purchases, iphone backups, playlists) for Windows reinstall

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, itunes

I need to reinstall Windows on my PC. How can I backup iTunes - app store purchases, iPhone backups, media library, iTunes U - and restore it to the new iTunes installation after Windows reinstall? I am using Windows 7 and iTunes 9.

Comment: Good question. You have my sympathy in advance.

Comment: Please i need to do that but the folder doesnt appears, could it be because i dont connect the iphone yet? do i have to do that and then copy the entire folder? please help me!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to go to C:\Users\<Your Username>\Music\ and copy over your ENTIRE iTunes folder (sometimes called iTunes Music) to a USB drive or some other backup location. When you reinstall Windows, install iTunes, but don't open it. Go back to that directory, delete the iTunes folder the installer created and move your copied folder back. Everything will be identical to how it was before you reinstalled (save for, of course, iTunes settings).

Comment: This will work on Windows as well as OS X; iTunes is nice that it keeps everything in one directory. This solution also assumes you have your entire music library consolidated in the iTunes Music folder (if iTunes is set to manage your music for you then you're ok). If not, now would be a good time to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Things to do:

1. Find the location of the folder where iTunes library files are stored.
2. Copy that entire folder. This takes care of your iPhone apps & the iTunes library file.
3. Head over to `%appdata%` and copy the Apple folder. This takes care of your iPhone backup files.

Comment: If you install iTunes from the Windows Store, the iOS backups will be in the `%UserProfile%\Apple` directory rather than `%AppData%\AppleComputer`.